# How can I access the object natraj from outside the class Item?

Tags: ruby

```
class Item
    def initialize(hash)
        @my_hash=hash
        return @my_hash
    end
end
natraj=Item.new({name: "pencil", quantity: 500})
```

Comment: `initialize` will always return the object itself no matter what. So in this case natraj is a `Item`. You could add `attr_reader :my_hash` or `attr_accessor :my_hash` to the class and then access with `natraj.my_hash`. `attr_reader` will create just a getter method where as `attr_accessor` will generate both getter and setter methods.

Comment: Thanks. It works. on printing natraj directly, we get Item 0x251f820.

what is this item code?

Comment: I believe that is the memory pointer for the object in question although it serves very little significance as it is implementation and interpreter specific.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this sort of problem is approached in Ruby with code like this:

```
class Item
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :quantity

  def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name]
    @quantity = options[:quantity].to_i
  end

  def to_h
    {
      name: @name,
      quantity: @quantity
    }
  end
end

natraj = Item.new(name: "pencil", quantity: 500)

natraj.name
# => "pencil"
natraj.quantity
# => 500

natraj.to_h
# => {:name=>"pencil", :quantity=>500}
```

As noted in the comments, `return` values in an `initialize` method is a special case and are ignored.